Why Dattatreya has three heads?
Why Dattatreya has three heads? The portrait of Dattatreya created by Raja Ravi Varma depicts him with three heads. Raja Ravi Varma was well-versed in Hindu scriptures. His paintings usually depict Puranic characters authentically. Markandeya Purana, Chapter 17 talks about Dattatreya. However, it did not mention his three heads! So I am curious about the reference to this portrait of three-headed Dattatreya.

I am not commenting about his Dhattatreyas painting but some of his paintings has Dhevis with untied hair.

The triple-headed six-armed deity is quite ancient, having been referenced in śilpaśāstra texts like Aparājitapṛccha (the current edition recorded by a Bhuvanadeva but the text claims itself to be conversation between Viśvakarmā & his son Aparājita) & Rūpamaṇḍana (composed by a Maṇḍana under the patronage of Kumbhakarṇa Sisodiyā aka Rāṇā Kumbha of Mevāra). But these texts refer to this form as Hari-hara-pitāmaha.

एकपीठसमारूढ़मेकदेहनिवासिनम् । षड़भुजं च चतुर्वक्त्रं सर्वलक्षणसंयुतम् ।। अक्षसूत्रं त्रिशूलं च गदां चैव तु दक्षिणे । कमण्डलुं च खट्वाङ्गं चक्रं वामभुजे तथा ।।
Translation: [The icon of Hari-hara-pitāmaha is to be conceived] in a single pedestal occupying a single body. It is to be six-armed, four-faced & endowed with all characteristics . In its right hands are the rosary, trident & mace. In its left hands are the kamaṇḍalu, khaṭvānga & discus [Aparājitapṛccha:213 & Rūpamaṇḍana:4]

Attriubution of this icon to Dattātreya arises from a faulty reading of the results of Anasūyā's chastity test. As shown here, Dattātreya is the avatāra of Bhagavāna Viṣṇu only, & not of the Trinity combined, which was aimed to be reinforced by this icon. Which of the following attribution - that of the icon of Hari-hara-pitāmaha or the claim of being the combined avatāra of the Trinity occured before is doubtful, but either one reinforced the other.
Here is the dhyānamantra of Dattātreya from a Tāntrika text called Dāśarathīyatantra

नीलजीमूतसङ्काशं जटामण्डलशोभितं । भूतिभूषितसर्वाङ्गं वीरासनसमन्वितं ।। पारिजाततरोर्मूले दिव्यसिंहासनाश्रितं । सनकादिमहायोगीसेवितं भक्तवत्सलं ।। मुद्रां ज्ञानमर्यां दक्षहस्ते वामेऽभयं तथा । पद्मनागसमायुक्तं हेमकुण्डलशोभितं ।। प्रसन्नवदनं शान्तं सुस्मिताननपङ्कजं । अनसूयात्रिसहितं ब्रह्मर्षिभिर्भिस्तुतं ।। सिद्धविद्याधरगणैः सेवितं च महर्षिभिः । दिव्याभरणसंयुक्तां वामभागस्थया श्रिया ।। सहितं नारदादैश्च सेवितं त्रिजगत्पतिं । दत्तात्रेयमहन्तियं भजामि परमेश्वरं ।।
Translation: I worship that ultimate great lord Dattātreya who is seated on a divine throne under the Pārijāta. His complexion is like that of a blue lotus, he is endowed with matted locks of hair. He is seated in the vīrāsana posture & his body is anointed with holy ash. He is fond of devotees & is served by great ascetics of likes of Sanaka. His right hand shows the jñanamudra & the right hand shows the abhayamudra. He is endowed with lotus (garlands), snake (ornaments) & golden earrings. His face is calm, recluse & beautiful like a lotus. Accompanied by Atri & Anasūyā, he is eulogised by brahmaṛṣis & served by siddhas, vidyadharas & mahaṛṣis. The lord of the 3 worlds is accompanied by Śrī bedecked with divine ornaments on his left side & is served by the likes of Nārada. [Dāśarathīyatantra:10:16-22]

Here is another from an 12th century Śaiva nibandha called Pratiṣṭhālakṣaṇasārasamuccaya

दत्तात्रेयं विभुं कुर्याद् द्विभुजं यौवनान्वितं । वामोत्सङ्गधृतश्रीकमर्धचन्द्रासने स्थितम् ।। वामपाणिधृताम्भोजां सुरुपां आयतेक्षणां । तद्दक्षिणं करं स्कन्धे देवदेवस्य दक्षिणे ।। सव्याश्लिष्टप्रियाः कार्यो दक्षिणे मद्यपात्रकम् । पद्मस्थो घुर्णिताक्षश्च गातृनर्तनकैर्वृत ।।
Translation: One should make (the icon of) Dattātreya having 2 arms & endowed with youth. He is to be seated on half-moon shaped pedestal with Śrī on his left lap. She has large eyes & a beautiful appearance. On her left hand, she has a lotus. Her right hand is kept on the right shoulder of the Lord of Lords. With his left hand, he hugs his beloved. In his right hand lies a vessel filled with alcohol. He is seated in padmāsana, his eyes are rolling (from intoxication) & is surrounded by singers & dancers. [Pratiṣṭhālakṣaṇasārasamuccaya:6:107-109]

 [Nepāli illustration of Dattātreya in a manuscript of Pratiṣṭhālakṣaṇasārasamuccaya found by Gudrun Buhnemann]

This Nepalese portrait is quite accurate because Markandeya Purana also says that the Goddess Lakshmi is seated on his left lap and he drinks Varuni wine.

All the texts say Dattatreya is the Avatara of Vishnu and Anasuya had three sons. So how on earth, this faulty reading is possible? I assume by mistake they think that Brahma, Vishnu and Siva are incarnated in one body as a son of Anasuya. This is strange!

How come the Silpashastra invented a new God Hari-Hara-Pitamaha? Because such an entity is not present in the Puranas. I am assuming someone identified Dattatreya with this entity. The Silpasastra does not talk about Dattatreya.

In Hooghly district, there is a large temple known as Brahma Dutta Dham. They have three other temples in three other corners of India. This temple has a three-headed deity, most probably Brahma-Vishnu-Siva. I used to wonder who is this deity. Now, I think it is Hari-Hara-Pitamaha.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Marathi Hindus are big into Dattatreya veneration. And apart from the misatributed form, they also venerate him in his one faced, two-armed form, which is likely a hold over from his older accurate icon.

Yes, the Guru of that sect is from Maharashtra.

I have heard another story that the Trimurthis incarnated as a single child but Atri and Anasuya wanted them to come as three different children. I don't know how accurate this story is.

Then what is the origin of Dhattatreya as a incarnation of Trimutis ?
